# Select row in twitter bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the style of a class inside the collapse link of a twitter bootstrap accordion. But when I change the style it changes the style of all the rows. I want to select only the one I clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          <div class="test"></div>Collapsible Group Item #1 
          </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           <div class="test"></div>Collapsible Group Item #2 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <div class="test"></div>Collapsible Group Item #3 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  var collapsing = $(this).data("toggle", "collapsing");
  collapsing.find(".test").html("Test");
})
```

#vacancy_panel is the id of the whole accordion. Inside the a tag there is a div with the class plus_icon.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/261/

I want only the test class of the clicked row content to change to test in this fiddle.

What I don't want to do is use the id of the row.

Comment: could you setup a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wait for the end of animation you can use :

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  var collapsing = $(this).data("toggle", "collapsing");
  $(".panel-collapse.in").prev().find('.test').html("Test");
})
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/262/

**UPDATE**

*If you absolutely need to perform it before collapse action, one way is to perform it on the click action...*

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/263/

**JS** :

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(){
    $heading = $(this).parent().parent();
    $panel = $heading.next();
    if(!$panel.hasClass('in'))
    {
        $heading.find('.test').html("Test");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually it is pretty important for me to have it at the start of the animation.

Comment: @SinanSamet Ok, there is another way, you can check my update.